# Linked List, pointer manipulation

Tags: c++, pointers

I am attaching below the code of `head_insert` to insert  a new node at the head of a linked list. The function is called with `head_insert(head)`.

I am not sure about the syntax of the first argument of the function, I was expecting `NodePtr`  instead since it is already a pointer, see below.

Why the code uses `NodePtr &head` and not `NodePtr head` only as head is already a pointer?

```
void head_insert(NodePtr & head, int the_number)
{
  NodePtr temp_ptr;
  temp_ptr=new Node;
  temp_ptr->data=the_number;
  temp_ptr->link=head;
  head=temp_ptr;
}


struct Node
{
  int data;
  Node *link;
};

typedef Node* NodePtr;
```

Comment: why the code uses "NodePtr &head" and not "NodePtr head" only as head is already a pointer?

Comment: Don't tag questions with both [c] and [c++]. While C++ understands C code, what is considered good style in C is rarely good style in C++.

Comment: @saraMcKnight: That should have been an edit, not a comment.

Comment: but even if u pass per value, head will be changed as head holds an address of the head node

Comment: i already edit my question

Comment: @saraMcKnight Yes, but what the function changes is that address itself, not the content stored at the address. This is only possible using a reference (or a pointer to pointer).

Comment: @saraMcKnight: Pointer allows you to change the object it points to, but to change where the pointer points you need a reference (or pointer) to it.

Answer (score 4):

> why the code uses "NodePtr &head" and not "NodePtr head" only as head is already a pointer?

The reason is that it needs any changes that the function makes to `head` to be visible to the caller.

If `head` were passed by value (`NodePtr head`) rather than by reference (`NodePtr& head`) this wouldn't be the case: when the function would assign `temp_ptr` to `head`, this change wouldn't propagate back to the caller. Passing `head` by reference addresses this.

Comment: but even if u pass per value, head will be changed as head holds an address of the head node

Answer (score 0):

Your typedef is a little confusing at first glance. In C, you should pass a `struct Node ** head` argument and assign its value to the newly created node : `*head = temp_ptr;`. Here is what it would look like :

```c
void head_insert(struct Node **head, int the number)
{
    struct Node *new_head = NULL;
    // Alloc memory for new_head, etc..
    new_head->data = the_number;
    new_head->link = *head;
    *head = new_head;
}
```

Thus, to make the assignment `*head = new_head`, you need to have a pointer to your list head which is also a pointer. Otherwise, the update performed in the function would remain local. In your code, you take a reference to a pointer, which has merely the same effect than passing a "double" pointer.

Comment: but if i used instead head_insert(struct Node *head,...)

Comment: If you did that, the `head = new_head` would not affect `head` outside the function.

Comment: It seems you are not aware of the stack behaviour. You should take a look at this SO question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap

Comment: Briefly, the memory for the arguments of your function is on the _stack_, this makes them __LOCAL__ to a function call. That said, if you modify the address pointed by your `struct Node *head` argument, it will modify the value on the corresponding stack area which is only related to the _current_ function call. Consequently, when you exit the function, you lose the assignment. Hence the need for `struct Node **head` (or a C++ reference).

Comment: Thanks Rerito...i get it now. any good textbook your recommend for further reading

Comment: @saraMcKnight : Since you seem more interested in C++, check out the following SO question : http://tinyurl.com/so-cxxbooks
Then, when you feel comfortable with C++ (and C), you can also dig in the system. A study of the Linux Kernel will bring you useful knowledge of how your program interacts with an OS